# How to keep 1 file from changing between branches

Tags: git

I have got branch master and beta on my local computer.

I work most of the time on beta, and when it is working fine I commit to master, but I have this `config.php` file which sets `debug=true` which I need when im working on beta.

```
config.php
```

Is there any way to keep this `config.php` file diferent on beta?

And if sometime I want to change something inside I would have to do it in master so I can push to live version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

include that file in git ignore file for the beta branch

Please follow this steps

1. add config.php in the .gitignore file
2. the above step needs to be run as soon as git repository is initialised using git init suppose you didn't add the file initially to .gitignore and git is currently tracking your file( as in your case ) use following command to let git stop tracking your file

   git rm --cached config.php

3.now when you try adding this file it throws out error that "the file is been ignored . if still you want to add it use -f option with git add". so ignore this warning when doing git add *

4.now even if you merge the branch with master(or any other branch) you won't see this changes out there i.e branch copy of file is reserved

hope this helps

Comment: if i update the git ignore file in the beta branch, and then merge, wouldn't the master update the git ingore?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more work than you would want to go through, but you could write a commit hook to look for that file getting changed on master and reject it if you see this file coming in with a change you don't want. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stop tracking changes on the file with:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree config.php
```

And you can resume tracking changes with:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree config.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your software should have a way for you to set `debug=true` in a **site configuration file** which is not present in the repository and not affected by an update of the software (such as your own develop-and-test cycle).

The shipping configuration in `config.php` should provide only default values, which are overridden by the user's site configuration file. There should be a warning in the file not to use it for local settings because it will be clobbered on each upgrade, and to create the local file instead.

Then, if the default config file needs to have different contents on different branches in your repo, just let it have different contents on different branches, just like any piece of code, documentation or any other artifact.

A nice touch might be for the install procedure to scan the site configuration file and report problems, such as references to variables which no longer exist, or whose names or behavior have changed, because these situations silently break the user's configuration, in effect.